# SQL Server 2005 setup unexpected failure during setup

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, msxml

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2005 Enterprise on Windows 2003 R2 SP2 (ESXi 5.0.0 guest). After installation of backward compatibility files and prior to MSXML6, I receive this error:

```
There was an unexpected failure during the setup wizard. You may review the setup logs and/or click the help button for more information.
```

This is a part of core log file containing error:

```
Running: InstallSqlAction.9 at: 2015/9/5 10:15:10
Installing: msxml6 on target: MONITORING
Error: Action "InstallSqlAction.9" threw an exception during execution.  Error information reported during run:
Target collection includes the local machine.
Invoking installPackage() on local machine.
Fatal Exception caught while installing package: "9"
        Error Code: 0x8007064a (1610)
Windows Error Text: The configuration data for this product is corrupt.  Contact your support personnel.

  Source File Name: sqlsetupactions\sqlsetuppackageutil.cpp
Compiler Timestamp: Mon Jun 13 14:30:05 2005
     Function Name: sqls::getPackageIsInstalled
Source Line Number: 50

---- Context -----------------------------------------------
sqls::InstallPackageAction::perform

WinException caught while installing package. : 1603
        Error Code: 0x80070643 (1603)
Windows Error Text: Fatal error during installation.

  Source File Name: packageengine\installpackageaction.cpp
Compiler Timestamp: Fri Jul  1 01:28:25 2005
     Function Name: sqls::InstallPackageAction::perform
Source Line Number: 167
```

It seems that configuration file has a problem, but what?! How can I fix this?

PS: The reason of installing SQL 2005 on Windows 2003 is that I have a network monitoring application which works only on this combination and can't upgrade to its latest version.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a new installer?

Comment: Not so far. Will give it a try.

Comment: Tried it with no luck.